# Make freshly connected external monitors always start with empty desktop

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, external-monitor

When I connect an external monitor to my laptop various windows I had open will end up displayed on that external monitor.
I am guessing it is remembering what windows were displayed where last time i had a monitor attached.

I will often move from my desk then to a meeting.
Occasionally, I will have mildly confidential documents open.
Now, I really should close them before leaving my desk but sometimes I forget.
Occasionally this results in confidential documents being shown to the entire meeting room.

So far nothing serious has been shown, the documents have been scrolled all the way to the bottom so it doesn't show any info etc.
But I want to be sure.

So I would like to know is there a setting somewhere so newly connected monitors start empty.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps, I found it very useful because I like my apps to open at my line of sight and not in any corner, specially useful for really big screens.

You can tweak this setting to tell Ubuntu to open new windows on the centre of the screen rather than in a corner or last position:

`gsettings set org.gnome.mutter center-new-windows true`

I don't use an extra monitor since I switched to Ubuntu, but if there is an option to set one as the main screen, it may solve your issue. Let me know.